# Make photo crumble when extra light falls on LDR

Tags: arduino, processing

For a couple of days now I have been trying to make a photo crumble away when I shine with a flashlight on a LDR. Both my Arduino code and Processing code work seperately, and I have established a handshake between those two. However, I don't know how to make something happen when the LDR messures a certain value. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Crossposted: http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/13171/make-a-photo-crumble-away-when-extra-light-falls-on-a-ldr

Answer (score 0):

Use firmata. I believe the StandardFirmata example should work

Comment: Did you just answer your own question with a solution you weren't certain of?